# it gives an error when i run a SQL script

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, syntax-error, sql-insert

I'm trying to INSERT INTO with SQL in a table in VBA but it gives a error while running this script. why?

I was expecting it to add the values to the table but it gives an error instead, does anyone has the solution for this?

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblScores (Student, Score, Date, ExamType, Lesson) VALUES (cbStudent.Value,txtScore.Value,txtDate.Value,cbExamType.value,cbLesson.Value);"
```

The error message:

[image: this is the error it gives]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:
Dim varStudent as String
.
varStudent = cbStudent
.
In SQL String: VALUES ( '" & varStudent & "', '" & varTxtScore & "'

'" = SingleQuote DoubleQuote

Comment: its actually what I was doing wrong! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The form values need to be concatenated to the SQL string, not being enclosed to it.

For example:

```
"WHERE ID =" & IdControl.Value
```

But this way is not recommended for various reasons. Best to create a temporary query and pass the values as parameters. If you need to run it frequently, create a permanent query and just call it - it will be slightly faster.

```
Const SQL As String = "PARAMETERS [Student] Text (255), [Score] IEEESingle, [Date] DateTime, [ExamType] Text (255), [Lesson] Text (255); " & _
                      "INSERT INTO tblScores (Student, Score, [Date], ExamType, Lesson) " & _
                      "SELECT [Student] AS [Student], [Score] AS [Score], [Date] AS [Date], [ExamType] AS [ExamType], [Lesson] AS [Lesson];"
                      
Dim q As DAO.QueryDef
Set q = CurrentDb().CreateQueryDef("", SQL) 'temporary query 
    q.Parameters("[Student]").Value = cbStudent.Value
    q.Parameters("[Score]").Value = txtScore.Value
    q.Parameters("[Date]").Value = txtDate.Value
    q.Parameters("[ExamType]").Value = cbExamType.Value
    q.Parameters("[Lesson]").Value = cbLesson.Value
    q.Execute
    q.Close
```

---

Keep in mind I don't know the actual data-types of your table fields, so some of the params could be off - the score for example.

Comment: why did my code work then? why does it give the Syntax Error. can i configure the code a little and make it work?

Comment: Your SQL string is incorrect. Text values need to be wrapped in quotes `' '` and dates in `#`.

Comment: it gives the same error with the ' ' ' ' for the texts

Comment: You have to do this for all text fields: "'" & cbStudent.Value & "'". Change `'` with `#` for the date. But as I said, this is not recommended. If a text value contains a quote, O'Brien for example, the sql will break. Parameters is the way to go.

Comment: i found the problem. i typed 'value' instead of 'Value' (i typed the V in lower-case)

Comment: nope that was not it